# highcharts stacked column draw horizontal line

Tags: highcharts

I need to draw horizontal line on highcharts stacked column as image below

[image]

In image Bold black line is showing, I need to draw same, however Bar color opacity changes when it split columns.

Comment: Add a line graph that is displayed on top that only does steps, like: https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/step-line

Comment: Let me Try @ewolden

Comment: @ewolden Thanks. Its Working for Black Bold Line :). but still looking for  Bar color opacity changes, but thanks lot for help :)

Comment: Please provide your code and the description of the problem if your chart still doesn't work as expected.